# Excel VBA code to set validation throws 1004 error

Tags: excel, validation

I go through the columns of a table, and for each column I go through the cells the check if the value meets the cell's validation. Now I want to add to my code: if the validation (that is present in the 2nd row) is missing in any other cell, the validation is copied to that cell.

First I create a Validation object of what is present in the second row:

```
Dim valMasterValidation As Validation
Set valMasterValidation = recordInTable.Range(columnInTable.Index).Validation
```

Then when a validation is missing in a cell, I add a validation as follows:

```
With recordInTable.Range(columnInTable.Index).Validation
   .Add Type:=valMasterValidation.Type, _
      AlertStyle:=valMasterValidation.AlertStyle, _
      Operator:=valMasterValidation.Operator, _
      Formula1:=valMasterValidation.Formula1, _
      Formula2:=valMasterValidation.Formula2
   .IgnoreBlank = valMasterValidation.IgnoreBlank
   .ErrorTitle = valMasterValidation.ErrorTitle
   .ErrorMessage = valMasterValidation.ErrorMessage
End With
```

However, the .Add part throws a 1004 error ("Application-defined or object-defined error").

Why is this and how must be the solution?

Additional information after further investigation: some validation formulas (= Validation.Formula1) will be copied without any problem, others raise the problem. E.g.:

```
=LEN(INDIRECT("tblCalibre[@CalibreName]"))>3
```

is OK, but

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("tblCountry[Country]");INDIRECT("tblCountry[@Country]"))=1
```

leads to an error.

Answer (score 0):

It was a locale issue... Reading .Validation.Formula1 obviously returns a formula with ";" inside, but writing must be done with ",". So my code has now:

```
With recordInTable.Range(columnInTable.Index).Validation
   .Add Type:=valMasterValidation.Type, _
        AlertStyle:=valMasterValidation.AlertStyle, _
        Operator:=valMasterValidation.Operator, _
        Formula1:=Replace(valMasterValidation.Formula1, ";", ","), _
        Formula2:=Replace(valMasterValidation.Formula2, ";", ",")
End With
```